# What should i do to get the co ordinates of touch using LongTouchListener

Tags: android

What should i do to get the co ordinates of touch using LongTouchListener.I can use onTouchListener coz it's easy to get coordinates there But i want to check the touch on specific ImageView as there are 3 of Imageview. So i am wondering if it's possible to get the cordinates on longtouch

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code.I have used it in ontouch event,so you can also use this in LongTouchListener

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

```
                Log.i("ImageStatus",""+status);

                System.out.println("X2="+event.getX()+"Y2="+event.getY());




                return false;
            }
```

here what you need is "event.getX()" for getting x-coordinate and "event.getY()" for getting Y-coordinate

Comment: Thanks Mate.. But i already had tried these things several times in my previous projects it's not gonna work here scenario is different